# Determine the intervals on which function $f (x) = x^3 + 6x^2 + 9x + 2$ is increasing.

Tags: calculus

Determine the intervals on which the function with equation $y = x^3 + 6x^2 + 9x + 2$ is increasing. What is the solution for this question? Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you compute the derivative $y'$?  do you know how to connect the derivative to your question?

Answer (score 4):

A differentiable function is increasing when its derivative is positive.

Computing the derivative:
$3x^2+12x+9$

We know that the function is increasing when this is positive. Can you find values of x for which:
$3x^2+12x+9>0$?

Answer (score 4):

$$f(x)=x^3+6x^2+9x+2\implies f'(x)=3x^2+12x+9=$$

$$=3(x^2+4x+3)=3(x+3)(x+1)$$

So now you have that

$$f'(x)\ge0\iff (x+3)(x+1)\ge0$$

Observe the above is a quadratic inequality, so if you identify its roots you can solve the inequality, and the problem, easily.

Answer (score 0):

When $$y = x^3 + 6x^2 + 9x + 2,$$ the intervals on which the function increases are given by the solutions to $y' > 0$.

In order to compute $y'$, we'll take the power rule on all of the terms. This provides $$y' = 3x^2 + 12x + 9.$$

To find the solutions to the inequality, $y' > 0$, we'll plug in $y'$ and observe.
This gives $$3x^2 + 12x + 9 > 0 \implies x^2+4x+3 > 0.$$

The solutions can be found from the quadratic formula.
$$x = \frac{-4 \pm \sqrt{16-12}}{2} \implies x = -2 \pm 1 \implies x=-1, \space x=-3$$
To find the total interval on which the derivative is greater than $0$, we need to check the point in-between the two critical points (at $x=-2$).
$$3x^2+12x+9 = -3$$
Thus, it is decreasing at the center of the two, so the interval must be outside of the interval $(-3, -1)$.
The intervals are at $(-\infty, -3)$ and $(-1, \infty)$

Comment: This isn't the best approach pedagogically; one can factor $x^2 + 4x + 3 = (x+1)(x+3)$ without using the quadratic formula.

Comment: Sure, but factoring doesn't work in many instances, so the quadratic formula is much more reliable as well as useful.